# Is it possible to dynamically repeat an element using HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So one of my friends is bugging me by sending lots of question marks, and I am supposed to send more question marks than them, so I am creating a webpage with an input field, which will take in all the question marks they want, I'll get the number of characters using the .length function, that's working fine.

The problem is, how do I show one question mark more than them? I am going to set a variable for number of question marks to be shown as `toshow= entered + 1` Entered is the number of characters entered.

So my question is how do I dynamically add either divs or question marks to a

tag which I made

Answer (score -1):

I didn't quite get your question, but you can try doing like

```
for (i = 0; i < charEntered; i++) { blockforquestionmarks.innerHTML += "?"; }
```

This way you'll recursively add questio marks to some block!

Comment: I can do this, but how do I make the question marks appear inside the div or the <p> tag?

Comment: If you want to dynamically add one html element to another. Then you should first create the element to insert into the other one: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp. And then do parent.appendChild(node); https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: you can do someElementLikePOrDIv.innerHTML = blockforquestionmarks.innerHTML